# ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d/%m/%y %k:%M)}

Tags: asterisk

how to print/noop next 2 day date

${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d/%m/%y %k:%M)}

it's displaying the current date, need to display next 2-day date.
where can change be made to get an output of next two day after date?
for ex. today 10 June need to display 12 June

Answer (score 1):

EPOCH is seconds since some date(depend of linux version).

So easy way is just add to EPOCH two days in seconds (60*60*24*2)

Comment: Thanks, it works                                                                                                     $[${EPOCH} + $[2 * 24 * 60* 60]]